# jumping outside loop in a specific case

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am writing a code that, for one or several lines of strings, find if the overall input has only "cool" (it's first middle and last string are the same) lines, only "uncool" lines or a mix of both.

The problem I'm having is whenever I input an even number the while loop terminates. Debugging I found that, just before jumping out n gets value 0 but I don't understand how this would make the loop end.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    // Bool has control if we have found a cool line/non-cool line
    bool cool = false;
    bool uncool = false;

    int n; //lenght of input
    while (cin >> n) {
        if (cool and uncool) break; // we have found one of each so we know it is a mixed input
        else if (n%2 == 0) uncool = true; // if the lenght is even there is no middle string
        else {
            // we are trying to see if the middle and last string are equal to the first
            string comparing_string;
            cin >> comparing_string;

            string rest_of_sequence;
            bool this_is_cool = true;
            for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--) { // we input the rest of strings and compare them to the first
                cin >> rest_of_sequence;
                if ((i == n/2 or i == 0) and rest_of_sequence != comparing_string) this_is_cool = false;
            }

            if (this_is_cool) cool = true;
            else uncool = true;
        }
    }

    if (cool and uncool) cout << "both types" << endl;
    else if (cool and not uncool) cout << "all cool" << endl;
    else if (uncool and not cool) cout << "none cool" << endl;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! I'm currently in first year of uni and always open to recommended books/webpages/videos to continue learning :)

Comment: replace  if (cool and uncool) break; to if (cool &&uncool) break;

That may help

Comment: @Saiful Why would it?

Comment: @SaifulIslam: Not really, given that [`and` means `&&`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#C.2B.2B_operator_synonyms).

Comment: `n` set to `0` as well as the loop finishing suggests that `cin >> n` extraction failed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I thought the program would just ignore input that wasn't an integer in the while loop, but it doesn't.

Now the code is correct:

```
else if (n%2 == 0) {// if the lenght is even there is no middle string
            uncool = true;
            string just_passing_input;
            for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) cin >> just_passing_input;
        }
```

Thanks for the helpful feedback, I shall now continue learning.